Spring doc generated OpenAPI spec validation
I'm using org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui for generating the openapi spec respectively the swagger-ui from my Controllers.
I'm not using the org.openapi.generator to generate the classes out of the spec, because it is not 100% supported for using Spring Boot and Kotlin.
What I would still like to do or use is the openApiValidate task to validate my generated OpenApi spec and be sure that my endpoints comply with the standard. But to use the task, you have to specify the path to the file, which is created in springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui at runtime.
Is there another way to validate the spec that is created?
Another idea of mine would be to have this validation step checked as a GitLab job.

In order to validate your spec using GitLab you can do a CI/CD job.
You have to write first a script to do OpenAPI spec validation (validate_openapi_spec.py for exemple) then add to gitlab a .gitlab-ci.yml, something as:
stages:
  - build
  - validate

# generation of spec and save it as artifact
generate_openapi_spec:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew generateOpenApiSpecValidation
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ../../spec.yaml
# execution of validation script (validate_openapi_spec.py) 
validate_openapi_spec:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - ./validate_openapi_spec.py ../../spec.yaml


thank you, but this is not helping out. it's not a full solution and this just what I said would do as second option.

You can use spring-boot-maven-plugin together with springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin for this.
The way it works is you actually run your application during build time (using the spring-boot-maven-plugin start and stop goals) and then download the generated OpenApi3 spec from the running application (by calling the http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs endpoint using the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin).
See:

https://springdoc.org/#plugins
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation#usingmavenplugin

Example config:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

By default the file will be downloaded under ${project.build.directory}/openapi.json, but you can configure a different directory / file name in the plugin's <configuration> section.
After that you should be able to validate the downloaded openapi.json file using any tool you like.

is there a way to do that in gradle?

Yes, see https://springdoc.org/#gradle-plugin
